# Python requests.get only responds if I don't specify page number

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am scraping web data with python using requests and beautiful soup. I have found that 2 of the websites I am scraping from only respond if I do not specify the page number.

The following code works and allows me to extract the data needed:

```
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)}

r = requests.get('https://www.milkround.com/jobs/graduate-software-engineer', headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
table = soup.find('div', attrs = {'class':'col-xs-12 job-results clearfix'})
```

If however I change the link to specify a page number, such as:

```
r = requests.get('https://www.milkround.com/jobs/graduate-software-engineer?page=2', headers = headers)
```

Then request never responds. There is no error code, the console just waits indefinitely. What is causing this and how do I resolve it?

EDIT: I opened the site in Incognito manually. It seems that when opening with the page number I get an "access denied" response, but if I refresh the page it lets me in?

Comment: Please provide the `headers` variable you establish.

Comment: see more header. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67798497/3981296

Answer (score 0):

That's because if you see, you are not able to access the page numbers on website from outside. So if you are logged in and have some sort of cookie then add it to your headers.

What I just checked on website is you are trying to access wrong URI.There are no page numbers. Did you add **?page=** from your own?

Comment: There are page numbers click on the second page

Comment: As a first suggestion, you might be able to access those pages due to some cookie values so you can add them to headers also. On my side its not opening so I am unable to dig deep

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're tackling with is about *web scraping*. In your very case, the web page you have blocks because your header declaration lacks of a proper user-agent definition.

To get it to work you need to include a user-agent declaration like this:

```py
headers={'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 0.5; en-us) AppleWebKit/522+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Safari/419.3',}
```

You can dive more deeply into the problem of writing good web scrapers here:
https://towardsdatascience.com/5-strategies-to-write-unblock-able-web-scrapers-in-python-5e40c147bdaf

A list of proper user-agents can be found here:
https://webscraping.com/blog/User-agents/

Hope it get's you working with your problem.