# requests.get(url) not returning for this specific url

Tags: python, web, python-requests, screen-scraping

I'm trying to use requests.get(url).text to get the HTML from this website. However, when requests.get(url) is called with this specific url, it never returns no matter how long I wait. This works with other urls, but this one specifically is giving me trouble. Code is below

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://www.carmax.com/cars/all', allow_redirects=True).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

print(soup.prettify().encode('utf-8'))
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36', "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1","DNT": "1","Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8","Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5","Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate"}
html = requests.get("https://www.carmax.com/cars/all",headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
```

Comment: Thank you so much, any chance you could briefly explain where I was going wrong?

Comment: You will need to define header.