# How to web scrape from equipment web server

Tags: python, web-scraping, ethernet

I am currently trying to webscrape from my weighing equipment. My weighing equipment has a load cell and a controller. The controller is connected to my laptop via ethernet. The controller has in-built web server, hence i can access the controller via chrome browser with the specified ip address 192.168.0.2 and toggle any settings and get weight data.

I am interested to web scrape the weight data from the web server using python and the supplied ip address. My code is below:

```
import requests
import bs4

result = requests.get("http://192.168.0.2")
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(result.text,"lxml")
x = soup.select('#DisplayWeight')
print(x)
```

However, i get the following errors:

1. `TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond`
2. `urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001B2A1EB2820>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond`
3. `urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='192.168.0.2', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001B2A1EB2820>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'))`
4. `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='192.168.0.2', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000001B2A1EB2820>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'))`

I dont understand what has gone wrong and i tried searching for answers. May i seek help on this. Thanks.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

You try provide header, this is example. ref:https://stackoverflow.com/a/67798497/3981296

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36', "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1","DNT": "1","Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8","Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5","Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate"}
html = requests.get("https://www.carmax.com/cars/all",headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
```

Answer (score 0):

The errors indicate that no response is being received.
You need to check that you have the right port number as well as the IP address.
For example, if the webserver is running on port 8080 you would have

```
result = requests.get("http://192.168.0.2:8080")
```