# How do I get around requests.get(url) taking forever for certain websites (Probably blocking a web scraper)?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I am very new to web scraping with **Python**. I am trying to build a **web scraper** that would scrape certain clothing websites for newest releases and their prices. However I am unable to get through requests.get(url) for certain websites(Ex:https://www.pacsun.com/).

I already tried the following based upon another post([requests.get(url) not returning for this specific url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67798296/requests-geturl-not-returning-for-this-specific-url)):

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36',
           "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
           "DNT": "1",
           "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
           "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
           "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate"}
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You say 'probably blocking a webscraper' but have you actually checked whether the requested website is otherwise reachable or not?

Comment: are the headers correct?

Comment: You could try Selenium

Comment: @Bialomazur yes the website is otherwise reachable

Comment: @jsotola I'm positive, because it works for most websites